# Why does C# prohibit internal access on interface members?

Tags: c#, interface, access-modifiers

C# deliberately prevents me from putting the internal access modifier on interface members. I'm pretty sure they had to put additional effort into implementing this restriction when they could have allowed it just as well.

There should be a good reason to spend that effort - which one?

For me it would be useful to have internal access modifiers on interfaces to realize "mutability prevention from the outside". E.g. consider the following interface:

```
interface IMessage
{
    ...
    DateTime LastSentTimestamp { get; internal set; }
    ...
}
```

Internally, within my message broker, I would like to be able to set the `LastSentTimestamp`. External users of my API should *not* be able to change it. Of course I could ditch the interface and use a class instead, however, this removes all the pros of interfaces (e.g. change implementation anytime, etc.)

**Q1:** I don't get it why they restrict me. Is there a particular reason?

**Q2:** I'm looking for a workaround for my particular situation above. Splitting the interface in two (`IMessage` and `IInternalMessage`) looks like a big pain in the ass and is hopefully not my only option left...

Comment: Because they didn't implement that.

Comment: Yes, they did. If they wouldn't have implemented it, I would be able to put the internal access modifier onto an interface member. (I can see, that you're attacking my second sentence, are you sure about that?)

Comment: Hey, I'm guessing anyhow.  My next guess is because of tacos.  Is that closer?

Comment: Sometimes SO members know details about implementation decisions and are able to answer such questions without guessing ;-) Thank you anyways for your attempt ;-)

Comment: Why exactly do you think this is explicitly prevented and easy to implement? An interface is a contract. Allowing modifiers would allow you to do stuff which can simply be done using a separate internal interface and inheriting the public one from it. The syntax you're proposing would add confusion IMHO. What if you pass an external implementation to your internal class? How would your internal class differentiate external from internal implementations? What would `set` do when invoked on a public implementation? Throw?

Comment: In my case `IMessage` objects are always created inside my framework, which is why I didn't realize the "public implementation given to internal framework" problem. See comment on accepted answer. Question is already answered, thank you anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the conflict that the C# designers have seen was that you cannot implement an interface with an `internal` member outside of the declaring assembly (and friend assemblies). Of course, it could still be useful to do this if outside assemblies only consume the interface. On the other hand you can get this behavior with a second `internal`-only interface:

```
public interface IPublic { /* all public members */ }
internal interface IPrivate : IPublic { /* additional members */ }
```

And your own classes implement `IPrivate`. External code can only use `IPublic`.

Comment: Outside implementations would not even know of the internal member they have to implement, so I would guess this should not be a problem. Your solution with another, internal-only, interface is a first workaround. Hopefully not my only option (see Q2 in question ;-)

Comment: Classes must implement all interface members. That's why external code can't inherit from `IPrivate` (in this case). What would invoking a missing interface method do? That's undefined because it is hard to define a useful meaning for that case.

Comment: Hmm, there is the underlying problem, I see. They could hand me implementations from the outside that would not implement that method! Thanks, this is the reason I was looking for.

Comment: Wouldnt the compiler bail out with something like [CS0060: inconsistent accessibility: base class is less accessible than derived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5732hs83(v=vs.90).aspx) when inheriting interfaces like that?

Comment: **precisely speaking, CS0061**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f82xxf1(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @usr: I think the intended meaning is to allow his public methods to accept as parameters things which have been returned by his factory methods, but not allow outside code to create objects satisfying those type constraints via other means.

Answer (score 1):

It's not your interfaces' members which should have access modifiers but the overall interface, so as to have consistent accessibility, and your classes. Interfaces only get used when implemented by a class. Interfaces express a contract which must be realized by an implementer. How would a class implement your internal member if it lived outside the interface's assembly? Thereby it is unable to implement the contract, but classes within must be able to...that's logically inconsistent.

Comment: ...you can see the use case above? Should I really split the interface in an IMessage interface and a second IInternalMessage interface? This doesn't look nice to me...so it could be more beautiful but they prevent it - why?